# Intent that extracts parameters and enforces GET using Unfiltered

Tags: scala, unfiltered

[Unfiltered](http://unfiltered.databinder.net/Unfiltered.html) offers an easy way to specify routes.

```
case GET(Path("/ask")) =>
```

It also offers an easy way to [extract parameters](http://unfiltered.databinder.net/Within+the+Parameters.html).

```
case Params(params) =>
```

What if I want to do both?  What is good style for this?  I realize I could:

1. use `case req @ GET(Path("/ask"))` and use `req.parameterValues`
2. match a second time on `req`
3. call `Params.unapply` directly

What *should* I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `&` like

```
case GET(UFPath("/int") & Params(params)) =>
```

See [ParamsSpec.scala#L38](https://github.com/unfiltered/unfiltered/blob/edc90673a8377357cc5b603a89f8d943524a057e/library/src/test/scala/ParamsSpec.scala#L38).